# WSL2 Kali won't stop and it always starts on boot

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, wsl2

After I noticed WSL2 was always running on my PC I wondered what was going on and after I checked noticed Kali was running and didn't matter what I did it didn't stop also I tried to reinstall everything but that also didn't change anything.

So, I was wondering if anyone has a solution for this problem so Kali stops once the terminal window is closed.

This is after running `wsl --shutdown` command even.
[image: WSL2 Kali running]

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots?

Comment: @harrymc Well I added the WSL state is there a specific screenshot that you wanted

Comment: Kali not stopping is not normal. Is that the question? And what have you done to stop it? Screenshots will be useful.

Comment: @harrymc Yes basically I want Kali to be the same as Ubuntu once the terminal is closed Kali should stop too and I reinstalled and repaired everything related to WSL2 also I tried `wsl --shutdown` and I didn't want to stop the services related to WSL2 because I do use WSL2 Ubuntu mainly

Comment: Does `wsl --terminate kali-linux` work?

Comment: @harrymc Nope anyway I tried to terminate or stop it `wslservice.exe` starts it again after a few secs and that's just Kali it's not even set as the default distro for WSL someone else had this problem on Reddit they managed to fix it by reinstalling but that didn't work for me

Comment: Found a [bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6878) about this issue. Check the two cases that are described as possible causes.

Comment: @harrymc Nope none of those it's a pretty fresh install and I never installed Kex on it

Comment: I meant more the possibility of a reference somewhere to `\\wsl$\kali-linux`, and especially in your recently used files (to be cleared as described).

Comment: @harrymc just cleared history and I still get the same result and I haven't added any sort of reference to that path I feel like this might be just a bug in WSL2 Kali or the setup that WSL2 Kali has maybe the setup makes some sort of reference

Comment: If `wsl --terminate` doesn't work, this is clearly a bug. Does Kali start up after reboot by itself?

Comment: @harrymc Yah everything else works pretty ok with Kali except that one thing

Comment: You can only file up another bug report, and workaround it by rebooting.

Comment: Yah true will do thanks

Comment: Sorry, started typing up that answer a few hours ago and just now completed it.  I agree with @harrymc's thinking that this is a "file being accessed" issue.  In my case, it was due to a browser download, but it could be other processes as well.

Comment: @poqdavid Just to confirm, I'm guessing that you are on Windows 11, right?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds yes Windows 11 22H2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a different approach.  This is still based on the theory in my [previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1746657/1210833), but a different way of trying to determine what's going on.

Since you have `autoruns.exe` already installed (from the comments), you may have the rest of the [SysInternals Suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) as well.  If not, install [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite), or at least [`Procmon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).  Then:

- Run `procmon.exe`
- *Filter* -> *Filter...* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, or the icon)
- Create a *Path* filter which *contains* `\\wsl`
- *Add* the filter to the list, and *Okay* the dialog
- Reset the display via the icon, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, or *Edit* -> *Clear Display*

Look for something accessing `\\wsl.localhost\kali-linux\...`.

I ended up finding that, for some reason, Asus Armory Crate is attempting to access some *old* (no longer on my system) distributions including Kali.  I'll be attempting to uninstall (and perhaps reinstall) to see if I can eliminate this.  But I really have no idea why Armory Crate is doing this.  Now I'm wondering if it could even be the same process on your system.

Comment: Fun fact I do have an Asus device and what you suggested is showing that `ArmouryCrate.UserSessionHelper.exe` is trying to access a file at this path `\\wsl.localhost\kali-linux\usr\lib\win-kex\win-kex` and since it doesn't exist it just fails its really surprising for me that process is trying to access Kali on WSL2

Comment: btw I did some more digging and as it turns out it's `AC_FDSPlugin` that's causing all that not the whole process

Comment: @poqdavid Well first, woohoo!  Glad we found it.  And amazed that this Asus process/plugin hasn't been noticed before in relation to WSL.  Is there a way to remove just that plugin that you've found?

Comment: Yah true this is very surprising to me also and I just renamed the plugin in `C:\Program Files\ASUS\ARMOURY CRATE Service\AC_FDSPlugin` and it's all fine but also at the same time not sure what that plugin does and also I found this https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/i0712x/support_armorycrate_privacy_concerns_unexplained/ looks like that plugin scans network drives for some reason xD

Answer (score 3):

*Short answer*:  Something in Windows may be attempting to access a file in `\\wsl.localhost\kali-linux`.  Whenever the path is accessed, the distribution will start, at least on Windows 11.

*More detail:*

I recently had a similar situation myself, but I don't know for sure that you are running into the same thing.

In my case, I had:

- Multiple distributions installed
- One of them was a specialized Debian distribution with a local Stable Diffusion installation
- `debugShell=true` set in `.wslconfig`.  This is a feature in WSL releases [0.51.2](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/0.51.2) and later that displays a separate debug shell whenever the WSL2 VM starts (or restarts).

I was noticing the debug shell (and thus the WSL2 VM) was starting up when I wasn't doing anything WSL related, usually shortly after booting Windows.  Then I noticed that it was happening when I launched by browser, Vivaldi.  And the only distribution that was starting up was the Stable Diffusion one.

If I renamed the distribution (via registry hack), it would no longer start.  If I named it back, it would start whenever starting Vivaldi.

I finally tracked it down to the fact that I had downloaded a file (the Stable Diffusion) checkpoint using Vivaldi directly into the distribution using the `\\wsl.localhost\<distro>` path.  When Vivaldi was starting, I believe it did a quick scan of each file in the list to see if it still existed.  This action caused the distribution to start.

In your case, you mention that Kali is restarting even immediately after closing it, which I'm assuming means that something has a file open in Kali and is trying to reopen it when it gets closed (the distribution stops).

If you have Windows 11, you can install a [Preview release from the Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage) to get that "visual indication" of exactly when Kali is starting.  Create or edit `%userprofile%\.wslconfig` (that's your *Windows* profile, not WSL) with the following:

```
[wsl2]
debugShell=true
```

Then `wsl --shutdown`.  The next time Kali starts on its own, you'll see a debug console window.  You don't need to do anything with it -- It will just be a visual indication that Kali started.  You can just close it out when it appears.

I'm hoping that might give you some indication of *exactly when* Kali is starting, and based on that, perhaps what is causing it.

Comment: I have WSL2 `0.66.2.0` do I need to get `0.68.4`?

Comment: @poqdavid If you have 0.66.2.0, then it already has the `debugShell` feature -- No need to go to 0.68.4 unless you want to.  If you do, see the instructions I provide [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1431790/1165986), but just skip the part about enabling Systemd (unless you want that as well).

Comment: Well I did what you said and WSL2 started right after I logged in to my account before anything else, like that was the first thing that came on my screen also my startup is very clean and I am sure the startup isn't the cause

Comment: @poqdavid It freaked me out when it happened, and took me a while to figure out what process had it.  You might want to load up [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) from the SysInternals suite (owned by Microsoft for quite a few years now).  It can show you everything that runs at boot to see if something might make sense.

Comment: @poqdavid Also, if you close out Kali, does it *immediately* restart and show another debug shell?

Comment: Oh I already checked Autoruns actually didn't find anything and yes it starts right after I stop it I even checked the process in Kali itself is there any sort of log that could show why its being triggered

Comment: Also, I just noticed when I switch to different applications the WSL2 Kali restarts itself which I didn't know that until I enabled the option you mentioned and it's not a specific application it's just any application in general

Comment: @poqdavid That's got to mean something, but what?  Any chance of a file having been downloaded into the distribution that a virus scanner would kick in on?  Speaking of, what's your antivirus -- Build-in Windows Defender or something else?

Comment: Well, I just tested WSL2 Kali by disabling my av software and it doesn't make any difference and the same thing happens

Comment: @poqdavid Okay, I'm going to write up something else to try, but what's your current WSL release?  Are you using the one that comes with Windows or a Store-installed (or otherwise) "Preview"?  `wsl --status`/`wsl --version`?

Comment: Here is the output for both commands
Default Distribution: Ubuntu, Default Version: 2, WSL version: 0.66.2.0, Kernel version: 5.15.57.1, WSLg version: 1.0.42, MSRDC version: 1.2.3401, Direct3D version: 1.606.4, DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp, Windows version: 10.0.22621.608

and yes I use the preview version from the store